# An object reference is required for the non-static field

Tags: c#, static

I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFgl71x1PX4) tutorial and I try to use a Access database in a C# console application.

I have 2 classes:

```
class Ac
    {
        OleDbConnection connection;
        OleDbCommand command;

        private void ConnectTo()
        {
            connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=D:\Info\csharp\socket\ef\accesstest\accesstest\bin\Debug\Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
        }

        public Ac()
        {
            ConnectTo();
        }

        public void Insert(string a, string b)
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Persons (nName, nNamee) VALUES (\"" + a + "\", \"" + b + "\");";
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And,

```
namespace accesstest
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        Ac f = new Ac();

        public static void Main()
        {
            f.Insert("ab", "ac");

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress enter to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And I get "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'accesstest.MainClass.f'". 
I try to remove the static from, but don't work, say the Main must pe static.

Any ideas for me ? Thank you !

Comment: Make `f` static `static Ac f = new Ac();`.

Comment: Or move it inside the `Main` method.

Comment: I'd say it would make more sense to move the instance creation of `f` into `main` - it doesn't seem to be serving any purpose anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer instance variable f without object reference in static context.

As per MSDN,The Main method is the entry point of a program; it is where the program control starts and ends.

- Main is declared inside a class or struct. Main must be static and it should not be public. (In the earlier example, it receives the default access of private.) The enclosing class or struct is not required to be static.
- Main can either have a void or int return type.
- The Main method can be declared with or without a string[] parameter that contains command-line arguments. When using Visual Studio to create Windows Forms applications, you can add the parameter manually or else use the Environment class to obtain the command-line arguments. Parameters are read as zero-indexed command-line arguments. Unlike C and C++, the name of the program is not treated as the first command-line argument.

[Suggested Reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Yes, I found all of these, but I couldn't understand what he means the problem with static. I understood the problem with Main, it was just an example to show I searched some times before posting. Thank you !

Comment: `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` actually does contain the executable as the first parameter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1) make "class Ac" public.

2) Make it simple

```
    public string whateverFunction()
    {
    f.Insert("ab", "ac"); 
    return "OK";}
    }
```

3) call MainClass somewhere else

```
    accesstest.MainClass obj = new accesstest.MainClas(); 
    string result = obj.whateverFunction();
```

if this works, improve the quality of the code